# Powershell mail merge only prints first page

Tags: powershell

I am using Powershell to script a mail merge using MS Word and the code below...  The merge executes correctly, however when I use the .PrintOut() command, only the first page is printed.

Is there anyway I can force it to print all of the pages from the completed merge?

Thank you.

```
$word = New-Object -ComObject "Word.application"
$word.visible = 1
$doc = $word.Documents.Open("$PSScriptRoot\resources\templateFile.docx")
$doc.MailMerge.Execute()
$doc.PrintOut()
$quitFormat = [Enum]::Parse([Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdSaveOptions],"wdDoNotSaveChanges")
$word.Quit([ref]$quitFormat)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try specifying [WdPrintOutRange](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.wdprintoutrange.aspx) as `wdPrintAllDocument`:

```
$doc.PrintOut(
    [ref]$false,
    [ref]$false,
    [ref][Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdPrintOutRange]::wdPrintAllDocument
)
```

Comment: Thank you... but unfortunately I'm still only getting the first page.

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured it out...  My original code opened the "templateFile.docx" file and then executed the Mail Merge which actually creates a new document called "Form Letters1.docx"

Simply issuing the $doc.PrintOut() command will print the original (non-merged) "templateFile.docx" which is only a single page.

The solution is to switch "focus" to the newly created / merged document before printing.

Here is the working code:

```
$word = New-Object -ComObject "Word.application"
$word.visible = 1
$doc = $word.Documents.Open("$PSScriptRoot\templateFile.docx")
$doc.MailMerge.Execute()
($word.documents | ?{$_.Name -match "Letters1"}).PrintOut()
Start-Sleep -Seconds 5
$quitFormat = [Enum]::Parse([Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdSaveOptions],"wdDoNotSaveChanges")
$word.Quit([ref]$quitFormat)
```

Another interesting point is the "Start-Sleep" command... without it, Word exits before it can get the merged document to the queue, resulting in nothing being printed.